# gzip compression not working on xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, gzip

for some reason the gzip is not working

my gzip compression script

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

i am using:----

XAMPP server.last time updated:2 min before the time of this question

NOTE:ALL FILES ARE A .PHP FILE,AND .HTACCESS FILES ARE IN ROOT FOLDER

HOW I FOUND OUT THAT IT IS NOT BEING GZIPPED:BY RUNNING AUDIT IN GOOGLE CHROME (DEVELOPER TOOLS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm betting your xampp install is not very old and you're probably using a recent version of Apache. So you should use `mod_deflate`.

`mod_gzip` is for `Apache 1.x` and `mod_deflate` is `Apache 2.x`

You can try this and customize as needed.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|txt|css|js|php|pl)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Or you can try it this way as well.

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif

#Custom Setting End.
```

You may also have to enable it in the Apache config. So you would uncomment this line and restart Apache.

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

You can also see gzip info here.
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

Comment: thanks my web Size, Markup (bytes) reduced from 54,134 to 5,512 compression% 89.8....is it enough?

Answer (score 5):

Uncomment this line on httpd.conf

- LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
- LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so